# React hooks compared to render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im pretty new to react and found out when you start a new project the boilderplate was a bit different then recently. Now it comes with something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

instead of as it used to be:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

The render function is gone. I found out it has to do with hooks.

Is the classes gone now in react? And so is the renderfunction? I know you still can use the "old way" but just to make sure I did get it right. It has to do with the hooks right?

What is the benifits with hooks compared the render and class way of writing components?

I guess this also applies to react-native ...

Comment: React is going functional now. Classes are gone, everything's now a function. There are no renders, just returns. This results in a cleaner and more performant code. However, you can stick with classes if you want.

Comment: @LiJonas you comment is not fair. It's absolutely false to say "classes are gone". They are not going anywhere for a long time.

Comment: @keul I meant that further development will be focused on functional components. Classes will continue to be supported in order to let older projects use the newest react version without migrating code to hooks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an old way or a new way. It's just two different ways that have existed for some time.

If you build simpler components without a state, you can use *Function Components*. That's the first notation you have in your post: A function that returns a JSX expression.

If you build more complex components that come with their own state, where it makes sense to implement them as classes, you can use *Class Components*. That's the second notation you have in your post: A class with a render function, which, in turn, returns a JSX expression.

Both are well-described in the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/).

Comment: React from v16.8 no longer suggests using classes and suggests migrating to functional components instead.

Comment: Would you have a source for that?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html section: `Should I use Hooks, classes, or a mix of both?`

Comment: @LiJonas to be more accurate. 16.8 suggests making **new** components to FCs. I only mention in because the word *migrate* can also be interpreted as a requirement to move existing infrastructure over to functional which is actually explicitly discouraged.

Comment: @apokryfos you are correct, migrating was an incorrect word

Answer (score 1):

**From React DOCS:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

> Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They **let you use state and other React features without writing a class.**

The render function isn't gone. Your functional components are still "render functions", as they'll return what should be rendered to the screen.

Before, in order to use `state` and have acces to other features like component life cycles, you needed to write your components as a class. With hooks, this is no longer necessary and you'll get access to `state` and other functionalities with much clearer API and syntax, in my opinion. Your code will get more readable.

**From Hooks FAQ:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html

> **Do I need to rewrite all my class components?**
>
> No. There are no plans to remove classes from React — we all need to keep shipping products and can’t afford rewrites. We recommend trying Hooks in new code.
>
> **Should I use Hooks, classes, or a mix of both?**
>
> When you’re ready, we’d encourage you to start trying Hooks in new components you write. Make sure everyone on your team is on board with using them and familiar with this documentation. We don’t recommend rewriting your existing classes to Hooks unless you planned to rewrite them anyway (e.g. to fix bugs).
>
> You can’t use Hooks inside of a class component, but you can definitely mix classes and function components with Hooks in a single tree. Whether a component is a class or a function that uses Hooks is an implementation detail of that component. In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.
>
> **Do Hooks cover all use cases for classes?**
>
> Our goal is for Hooks to cover all use cases for classes as soon as possible. There are no Hook equivalents to the uncommon `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` and `componentDidCatch` lifecycles yet, but we plan to add them soon.
>
> It is an early time for Hooks, and some third-party libraries might not be compatible with Hooks at the moment.